my programmr of casar space always chance to other things
my programme decrypt some poem,but the result of decrpy have a problem.
My other words are correct,but my space will turn to different words like { and t
and i don't know the reasons
def Check(input_text):
    allowed_chars = ''.join(chr(i) for i in range(32, 127))
    for i in input_text:
        if i not in allowed_chars:
            return False
    return True
def Decrypt(input_text, key):
    decrypted_text = ""
    for char in input_text:
        if 32 <= ord(char) <= 126:
            decrypted_char = chr((ord(char) - 32 - key) % 95 + 32)
            decrypted_text += decrypted_char
        else:
            decrypted_text += char
    return decrypted_text
def ShowAllDecryptions(encrypted_text):
    print("\nDisplay all possible decryption results (key from 0 to 94）：\n")
    for key in range(96):
        decrypted_text = Decrypt(encrypted_text, key)
        print(f"Key {key}: {decrypted_text}")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    encrypted_text = input("Please enter the text to be decrypted:")
    if not Check(encrypted_text):
        print("The text entered is invalid. Please use only ASCII characters.")
    else:
        print("\nPlease select the decryption method：")
        print("1. Decrypt using a specific key")
        print("2. Show all possible decryption results")
        decrypt_choice = input("Please enter your choice（1/2）：")
        if decrypt_choice == "1":
            try:
                key = int(input("Please enter the key (integer) used for decryption："))
                decrypted_text = Decrypt(encrypted_text, key)
                print("\nThe decrypted text is:", decrypted_text)
            except ValueError:
                print("key Invalid input, please enter an integer.")
        elif decrypt_choice == "2":
            ShowAllDecryptions(encrypted_text)
        else:
            print("Invalid selection, please rerun the programme")

i try to use different poem to find out thw bug ,but i can't find it .I hope someone can help me solve this problems

Please edit your question and add a copy of the original text, its encrypted result (and the code that encypted it), and the final decrypted version.

Please clarify which particular encryption algorithm you're trying to implement. It looks like some kind of symmetric-key approach

The OP mentions a Caesar chipher. But it looks like it accepts a wide range of characters From white space (ascii code 32) to the tilde symbol (ascii code 126). It looks like given an encrypted message the OP wants to apply all possible 95 rotations to decode it.

@Cincinnatus I don't think the Caesar Cipher algorithm involves any kind of key. It's just based on a shift value

The key is the shift value. If you see the code, the OP substracts the ASCII value of the first character to make it referenced to 0, then substracts the key and then does the modulo 95 and then adds the ASCII of the first character to undo the reference to zero.
